# Copy and paste in vim via keyboard between different mac terminals?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, copy-paste, iterm

Can anyone help me with this:
I'm trying to figure out how to copy and paste text between 2 different instances of vim on different terminals (using iterm2 or mac terminal). I can do it using the mouse if I do ":set mouse=a" but I'd like to be able to do it using the keyboard.

I've googled around and it says you can use the "* or "+ registers to copy/paste to/from the system clipboard, but when I type * or + in vim, the mac makes one of those sounds it makes when you can't do something. I've also done ":set clipboard=unnamed" but that hasn't worked either.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion) and iTerm2 or Mac terminal.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just as a side-note;  when I wanted to do something like this, I eventually realised that the easy way to achieve it was not to run two different vim instances in separate terminals at all, but instead to have several splits or buffers in a single vim instance, so I could look at several files at once in just one vim.  Then it's not even an issue at all, and you can yank and put text between those files to your heart's content without any special effort, or learning new commands or anything.

Comment: To use the system clipboard, I use the sequence `"*y` for yanking to it and `"*p` or `"*P` for pasting from it. And yes, I like to have more than one window, and to switch between them by using `ALT-TAB`. This is much easier than using one window for VIM and there 2 different directories with some files in it.

Comment: I use only one Vim and do all the file navigation/opening from within Vim via LustyExplorer. All the buffers I've opened in a session are hidden and accessible very quickly via the same plugin. Using only one Vim allows me to share registers (and thus macros) and history between all my open buffers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could you add the output of `:version`?

I can yank with `yy` or `y` in one Vim instance running in Terminal.app window A and put with `p` or `P` in another Vim instance running in Terminal.app window B with this line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

without using specific clipboard registers (`*` or `+`).

And why do you have two Vim instances running in different terminals? SSH/local? If one is in an SSH session yanking/putting won't work because the two machines (local/remote) don't share the same clipboard(s).

**EDIT**

I suspected that Vim wasn't compiled with the right flag(s). Apparently that's the case.

Since you are using Mac OS X's default Vim my opinion is that you shouldn't need to re-compile it or even compile anything as it often leads to more problem's than it's worth.

Instead, download the latest MacVim build and use the (CLI) Vim executable within MacVim's bundle: it has all the same functionalities as MacVim (within the constraints of the CLI, of course).

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or wherever you are used to put aliases and custom bash functions:

```
alias vim='/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
```

Comment: Here's my version output: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 24 2011 20:00:09)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.

Comment: I've tried what you said, having 2 terminal windows open, each one with an instance of vim. But I still can't copy and paste between them (even with :set clipboard+=unnamed in my ~/.vimrc)

Comment: Ah, I just noticed this in the version output: -xterm_clipboard. So I guess I'll need to recompile vim and enable xterm_clipboard or something? How do I do that?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes the problem is the missing flag. No you don't need to compile a new Vim. Instead download and install MacVim and use the CLI executable hidden in the bundle as per this [answer of mine](http://superuser.com/questions/311356/already-have-vim-installed-how-to-re-install-over-existing/311816#311816).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an entire file into your target file.

Open your target file in vim.

Put your cursor where you want it and type the following:

:r /path_to_file/file.ext

This will copy an entire file to where your cursor is...

Comment: You could link answers in different stack exchange sites by adding a comment with a link to your original answer. There is no need to duplicate content by copy-pasting.